# Jackson Mr Bean Bean Materializer support for toString implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-modules

I am using Jackson Mr Bean module to construct impl classes for defined interfaces. It works great, but one problem is that it does not generate an (overriden) implementation of `toString()` in the impl class resulting in the inability to use it for logging.

I worked around it by using default methods, but it would be nice to have that support..does any one know of a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe worth filing an issue; there are some for "equal()"s etc, but `toString()` would be easier (depending on ideal logic -- maybe just String of `Class` being implemented?)

Comment: filed a ticket & gave the link to it below...thanks again!

Comment: Below is the link,
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/122